# lambda function query in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, lambda

How do I get this lambda function to work? I want to inspect the value in the 'work_year' column and if it is less than 2023 I want to multiply the 'salary_in_usd' figure by the inflation rate data in columns '2020', '2021' and '2022' to get an inflation adjusted salary

```
merged_df = merged_df.assign(cpi_adj_salary = lambda x: x.salary_in_usd if x['work_year'] == 2023 
                             else (x.salary*(x[['2022']]/100 +1) if x['work_year'] == 2022 
                                   else (x.salary*(x[['2022']]*x[['2021']]/100 +1) if x['work_year'] == 2021
                                         else (x.salary*(x[['2022']]*x[['2021']]*x[['2020']]/100 +1)))), axis=1)
```

Here is the merged_df.to_dict output:

<bound method DataFrame.to_dict of       work_year experience_level employment_type                 job_title  
0          2023               SE              FT  Principal Data Scientist
1          2023               SE              FT            Data Scientist
2          2023               SE              FT            Data Scientist
3          2022               SE              FT            Data Scientist
4          2023               SE              FT            Data Scientist
...         ...              ...             ...                       ...
3747       2021               MI              FT            Data Scientist
3748       2020               SE              FT        Lead Data Engineer
3749       2021               MI              FT         Big Data Engineer
3750       2021               EN              FT     Business Data Analyst
3751       2021               MI              FT             Data Engineer

```
  salary salary_currency  salary_in_usd employee_residence  remote_ratio  \
```

0      80000             EUR          85847                ESP           100
1      45000             EUR          48289                ESP             0
2      36000             EUR          38631                ESP             0
3      84000             EUR          88256                ESP           100
4      45000             EUR          48289                ESP             0
...      ...             ...            ...                ...           ...
3747   21600             EUR          25532                SRB           100
3748  125000             USD         125000                NZL            50
3749   18000             USD          18000                MDA             0
3750   50000             EUR          59102                LUX           100
3751   24000             EUR          28369                MLT            50

```
 company_location company_size  2020  2021  2022  2023
```

0                  ES            L  -0.3   3.0   8.3   4.3
1                  ES            M  -0.3   3.0   8.3   4.3
2                  ES            M  -0.3   3.0   8.3   4.3
3                  GB            L  -0.3   3.0   8.3   4.3
4                  ES            M  -0.3   3.0   8.3   4.3
...               ...          ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
3747               DE            S   1.6   4.1  12.0  12.2
3748               NZ            S   1.7   3.9   7.2   5.5
3749               MD            S   3.8   5.1  28.6  13.8
3750               LU            L   0.0   3.5   8.1   2.6
3751               MT            L   0.8   0.7   6.1   5.8

[3752 rows x 15 columns]>

Comment: Use `numpy.select`